# How do I draw on a vector map in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, digitizing

I have a vector map that has two lines. I want to have the two connected. Is there a way for me to draw a line to connect the two? I am using GRASS gis by the way. The two lines that I want to connect are shown here:
[image]

Comment: which file format do you use?

Comment: Do you want to modify the data underlying the map or just draw a line on the map?

Comment: I just want to draw a line on vector map (.shp).

Comment: You need to go into editing mode :) See the menu where "2d view" is written. Note that this works in GRASS 7 and will do so in the future 6.4.2. Otherwise launch "v.edit" from command line or from the menu.

Answer (score 3):

try v.edit

[image]

Comment: I tried running v.edit then add, but it still did not connect the two lines

Comment: see the option parameters : http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass63/v.edit.html The *tool=merge* option seems to be appropriate, no?

Comment: In the settings, set the appropriate snapping distance. Easiest done in map units.

Comment: I tried v.edit map=vector tool=connect id=1,2 thresh=-1,700 but it still did not connect

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a nice use case possibility of [Quantum GIS](http://qgis.org) as an interface to GRASS, helped by the standard "GRASS ToolBox" plugin :)

Comment: Please also indicate how qgis might be used in this example. Otherwise one could just as easily say "this is nice use case for using Mapinfo for ...", or any other of the hundreds of programs which can edit and join lines.

Comment: QGIS can integrate nicely with GRASS, and act as a graphic interface, with the help of the standard "GRASS Toolbox" plugin. Cf. the tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=using+grass+qgis+tutorial&aq=f

Comment: Nice. I didn't know there was a collection of video turorials. I'd fold the comment into your answer so it's all in one place (use the [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/9007/edit) link in grey under the post)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use v.edit to snap or connect lines but it seems not to work. Actually on connect does nothing, and on snap delete the lines. You should try v.clean, which also has the snap option, but with v.edit you can also use a query, so is nicer.