# How to extend lines in Grass

Tags: grass-gis, vector

I have a set of vector lines in grass which I need to convert into polygons.  However, because of bad base data, the polygons don't always close.  To fix this, I need to extend each disjointed line by a certain distance and connect it to the first line it hits.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this.  I have experimented with v.clean, v.generalize, v.edit, and (converting to a thinned raster) r.grow, r.neighbors and even r.flow, but I can't find anything which will let me do this.

Can anyone point me to a tool that would do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I draw on a vector map in GRASS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/how-do-i-draw-on-a-vector-map-in-grass)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the tool `v.clean` with the option `tool=snap` and specify the correct `thresh` setting to snap the lines to the closest vertex. More details can be found here [1]

[1] http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.clean.html

Comment: I tried that, but there are two problems: 1, it seems to snap to the first point found in threshold, not necessarily the closest.  And 2, it also snaps ends which are already joined together.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if there aren't too many polygons to edit, you could the use vector digitizer in the wxgui                                  http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/wxGUI.Vector_Digitizer.html

Comment: Only a few million...  It definitely needs to be automatible.

Comment: ... then http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.edit.html will be interesting.

Comment: I looked at v.edit, but can't see a way to do it with that either.

Comment: Please look again: you can define the area of interest where the operation should be applied (to avoid wrong snapping).